# How do I Display the results of a sub routine in derived class in a button

Tags: vb.net

The results displayed in a window button from a sub routine in a derived class keeps giving me zero. I am not sure if my way of instantiating the class was wrong or my calculation was wrong as I am new in programming.

This is the base Class:

```vb
Public Class Books
    Private _NumberOfBooks As Integer
    Private _Points As Decimal
   
    Property NumberOfBooks() As Integer
        Get
            Return _NumberOfBooks
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _NumberOfBooks = value
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Property Points() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Points
        End Get
        Set
            _Points = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub CalculateNumberOfBooks()
        NumberOfBooks = 0       
        NumberOfBooks += NumberOfBooks       
    End Sub
   
    Sub CalculatePoints()
        If NumberOfBooks > 0 And NumberOfBooks <= 3 Then
            Points = NumberOfBooks * 10
        ElseIf NumberOfBooks > 3 And NumberOfBooks <= 6 Then
            Points = NumberOfBooks * 15
        ElseIf NumberOfBooks > 6 Then
            Points = NumberOfBooks * 20
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Below is the derived Class:

```vb
Public Class ElementaryGrades
    Inherits Books
    Dim _NumberOfBooksRead As Integer
    Dim _Point As Decimal
    Property NumberOfBooksRead() As Integer
        Get
            NumberOfBooksRead = _NumberOfBooksRead
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _NumberOfBooksRead = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property Point() As Decimal
        Get
            Point = _Point
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Decimal)
            _Point = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New()
        MyBase.CalculateNumberOfBooks()
        NumberOfBooksRead = NumberOfBooks
    End Sub

    Sub PointCalculation()
        MyBase.CalculatePoints()
        Point = Points
    End Sub
End Class
```

Below is the Window form to display the result:

```vb
Public Class Form1   
    Dim Operation As New Books
    Dim Calc As New ElementaryGrades
   

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim NofBooks As Integer
        NofBooks = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
        NofBooks = Operation.NumberOfBooks.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub PointsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PointsToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            Button1.Text = Calc.Point.ToString       
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hmm, `Sub CalculateNumberOfBooks()  NumberOfBooks = 0  NumberOfBooks += NumberOfBooks  End Sub`. Could you format the code in your question? It's kind of unreadable.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the editing.

Comment: I am new to programming, however I can't figure out why I am not getting results displayed in button1

Comment: I am sorry about that @Craig. Thank you for the editing.

Comment: Your Property getters are almost all wrong, as the assignment I've mentioned in the first comment. You should spend some more time studying the examples you can find in the Docs to master these basics. In a getter, as in `Point as decimal`, you cannot have something like this: `Get  Point = _Point  End Get`. A getter returns a value, you're instead assigning the value of a backing field to the Property itself. See what you have in the `NumberOfBooks As Integer` property. See also auto Properties in .Net.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I am not sure that ElementaryGrades should inherit Books. There should be a "is a" relationship. Class Animal can have a derived class Dog because a Dog **is an** Animal. A Person class might have 2 derived classes; an Employee and a Customer because an Employee **is a** Person and a Customer **is a** Person. Is ElementaryGrades a Books?

Comment: The code in your TextChanged even makes no sense. You declare a variable as Integer. You assign the value in the text box. On the very next line you assign something else but you call .ToString which can't be assigned to an Integer variable.

Comment: Since you never set any properties of your objects you will get nothing but zeros.

Comment: `CalculateNumberOfBooks` will never give `NumberOfBooks` anything but zero.